# Are sinks in DEM considered to be errors?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, dem, spatial-analyst, sink

According to [How Sink works](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-sink-works.htm) in the ArcGIS Desktop 10.3 documentation:

> Naturally occurring sinks in elevation data with a cell size of 10
>   meters or larger are rare (Mark 1988), except in glacial or karst
>   areas, and generally can be considered errors. ([source](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-sink-works.htm))

Lakes, ponds, valleys, volcanoes are all naturally occurring "sinks". In fact, any non-monotonic topography has "sinks".

So why are sinks in DEM considered an error?

Comment: Such a person has never mapped the Australian arid regions to make a statement like that.

Comment: I think the specific case is hydrology, where the modelling assumes rivers / streams. Possibly from early SRTM data where really rapid changes confused the results and produced voids in the data.

Answer (score 1):

Esri has a good distilled explanation in their [How Fill works](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/how-fill-works.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_C1EB0CA865774670972390988257C026) documentation:

> Sinks (and peaks) are often errors due to the resolution of the data
>   or rounding of elevations to the nearest integer value.
>
> Sinks should be filled to ensure proper delineation of basins and
>   streams. If the sinks are not filled, a derived drainage network may
>   be discontinuous.

Comment: I understand that drainage calculation requires filling up sinks. The question is why they deem it as data errors in the first place.